blank screen with 'x' cursor after log in ( dualboot ubuntu)
I have a dualboot machine with Windows 11 23H2 and Ubuntu 24.04 . After I switch from RAID to AHCI, turn off fast boot and security boot, I log in to the Ubuntu and I stuck at a black screen with a 'X' shape mouse pointer. Is there any clues to solve this problems?
I tried to check the system journal log by journalctl -b -1 | grep -i error and it seems that I got an ACPI error and GNOME/DBus errors

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
